# Перегрузка оператора сравнения и структура Set

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов, операторы

Перегрузил оператор для своего класса. В отдельных выражениях при сравнении ошибок нет

```
cout << (StringLocation("123", 123) < StringLocation("123", 124)); // Вывод: 1
```

Но при добавлении в `set`

```
map<string, set<StringLocation> > A;
A["123"].insert(StringLocation("123", 213));
```

Возникает ошибка:

> no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'const StringLocation' and
>   'const StringLocation')

Как обозначить этот оператор сравнения, чтобы его видел `set`?

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class StringLocation {
private:
    std::string FileName;   // Имя файла
    int lineOfLocation;     // Номер строки
public:
    StringLocation(std::string FileName_, int lineOfLocation_)
    {
        this->FileName = FileName_;
        this->lineOfLocation = lineOfLocation_;
    }
    std::string getFileName ()
    {
        return this->FileName;
    }
    int getLineOfLocation ()
    {
        return this->lineOfLocation;
    }
    /*
     *  Перегрузка оператора сравнения
     */
    bool operator < (const StringLocation& my_StringLocation)
    {
        if(this->FileName == my_StringLocation.FileName)
            return this->lineOfLocation < my_StringLocation.lineOfLocation;

        return this->FileName < my_StringLocation.FileName;
    }
    /*
     *  Перегрузка ввода/вывода
     *
     *  Выполняется только в том случае, если в основном файле
     *  подключена библиотека <iostream>
     *
     *  _GLIBCXX_IOSTREAM в MinGW
     *  _IOSTREAM_        в MSCVS
     */
    #if defined(_GLIBCXX_IOSTREAM) || defined(_IOSTREAM_)
        friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, const StringLocation& my_StringLocation)
        {
            out << "Line " << my_StringLocation.lineOfLocation << ": " << my_StringLocation.FileName;
            return out;
        }
    #endif
};

int main()
{
    map<string, set<StringLocation> > A;

    A["123"].insert(StringLocation("123", 213));
}
```

**UPD**:

Как быть, если нужно написать оператор != для итераторов?

```
// Такая проверка не работает :C
bool operator != (const StringLocation& my_StringLocation) const
{
    return this->FileName != my_StringLocation.FileName && this->lineOfLocation != my_StringLocation.lineOfLocation;
}

std::set<StringLocation> get_info_about_word (std::string word)
{
    auto it = this->invertedIndex[word];
    if(it != this->invertedIndex.end()) // Сравнение!
        return it;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сделайте его константным:

```
bool operator < (const StringLocation& my_StringLocation) const
```

А то получается, что ваш оператор сравнения пытается изменять сравниваемый объект :) А `set` "на энто пойтить не может" (с) :)

Comment: Проблема решена

Comment: Можете посмотреть дополнение к вопросу?

Comment: `invertedIndex` - это что? У вас в классе такого вроде нет.

Comment: ``invertedIndex `` - поле другого класса. this->invertedIndex возвращает map<string, set<StringLocation> >

Comment: error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'std::set<StringLocation>' and 'std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::set<StringLocation> >::iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::set<StringLocation> > >}')|

Comment: Хотя, вроде, и без проверок ничего не ломается

Comment: Извините, что-то не очень понятно. Вы можете привести минимальный самодостаточный пример - и, наверное, уже в новом вопросе (выдирать код из комментариев - не самое веселое занятие).